# VS code Emmet multiplying code not working in html

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

I have started to use Visual Studio Code and am having issue's with Emmet.

When I type in the code `ul>li` and hit tab to expand, it expands. But when I try to multiply the code like `ul>li*3`, it does not expand and I get no suggestion for that abbreviation. I have added `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true` to the json file, and that did nothing, and I have restarted all extensions with the restart extension host command.

All suggestions on how to fix this issue are appreciated.

Comment: In my experience disabled `emmet.useInlineCompletions` makes emmet rather hit-or-miss type of experience...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I am facing this issue too since latest update.

Somehow the solution I have got is :
You can check the box “Emmet: Use Inline Completions”
In settings by typing “emmet” in the setting’s search.
After checking the box You can see the suggestion and choose it by pressing the tab.

This is the solution I have got till now but hoping that we could have the previous version back.

Answer (score 1):

You can get them back consistently by turning Inline Suggest on.

If you find that annoying or distracting, you can leave that off and use ctrl+space to get the old popup shortcut to come up, and then hit tab as normal.